# Will android/bitmap.h increase performance in image processing

Tags: performance, android-ndk, android-bitmap

I am making an image processing APP in Android. Originally, I use Java to do the pixel computing, it is extremely slow. Then I change to C++ native code, it's much faster, but not enough.

I just pass the pixels integer array to C++, and do the computing. Recently, I noticed the `android/bitmap.h` library, but I am not sure whether it will increase performance. It seems like the difference is just passing an integer array or a bitmap. If I still need to do the same computations, how could it be faster?

Comment: Hey there! Did you possibly need more help with your question? You haven't marked this question as answered so I figured I'd reach out.

Comment: Why is java extremely slow ? Can you share some code ?

Answer (score 0):

I should preface that I have never written code using the NDK or the Bitmap library, but I did take a look at the documentation for it.

The [Bitmap.h](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/bitmap_8h.html) documentation looks like it's only used for meta information about the Java Bitmap object. It only provides a single struct that tells you basic information about the bitmap (width, height, etc), its format, and other similar data. The library also only contains functions for performing locks on the data or getting the aforementioned information.

Therefore, I would conclude that using the Bitmap library in the NDK is **only** useful if you are writing Java and C++ code in parallel and you use Bitmap objects in the Java code, in which case you might want to use the library to interact with them easily. There will be no performance gains, and it might not even make sense, to use the bitmap library otherwise.

Take a look here for an example on the usage of the Bitmap library: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/bitmap-plasma.
Notice how the Bitmaps are created in the Java code and then only processed in the C++ code.